# MATLAB: How do I clean up this "if" block?

Tags: matlab

I have an if...elseif...elseif...block, and I thought that I only need a single "end" at the very end. However, I get an error unless I put an end for each individual "elseif" statement. The code is shown in the following:

```
if final_grade >= 90;
    letter_grade='A+';
else if final_grade < 90 & final_grade > 80;
       letter_grade='A';
else if final_grade < 80 & final_grade >= 76;
        letter_grade='B+';
else if final_grade < 76 & final_grade >= 73;
        letter_grade='B';
else if final_grade < 73 & final_grade >= 70;
        letter_grade='B-';
else if final_grade < 70 & final_grade >= 60;
        letter_grade='C+';
else if final_grade < 60 & final_grade >= 50;
        letter_grade='C';
else if final_grade < 50 & final_grade >= 40;
        letter_grade='D';
else if final_grade < 50 || exam_grade < 50;
        letter_grade='F';
else if exam_grade < 50
        letter_grade = 'F'; 
    end
    end
    end
    end 
    end
    end
    end
    end
    end
end
```

For some reason, this is the only way my code will work. If I only write one "end", MATLAB tells me that one or more ends are missing. Does anyone know how to compress this to one final "end"?

Comment: [Reading the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) would probably be helpful.

Comment: Plus last line is useless as it's already checked above (`exam_grade<50`)

Comment: For your `elseif` conditions you don't need to check the upper bounds, because previous conditions would have matched. This assumes your conditions are in the right order.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that this is what you want:

```
    CENT_GRADES = [  40,  50,   60,   70,  73,   76,  80,   90];
    LETT_GRADES = { 'D', 'C', 'C+', 'B-', 'B', 'B+', 'A', 'A+'};

    ix_grade = find(final_grade >= CENT_GRADE, 1, 'last');

    if exam_grade < 50 || isempty(ix_grade)
            letter_grade = 'F';
    else
            letter_grade = LETT_GRADES{ix_grade};
    end
```

Please note that the execution is different from yours: someone cannot pass the exam with `exam_grade` smaller than 50.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `elseif` keyword instead of the two keywords `else if`.  This keeps things at the original level of nestedness.